# Is it possible to make scalatest to discover within package object?

Tags: scala, scalatest, java-package

I have several test facets sharing multiple test classes, so I aggregate them into a trait to be mixin into package objects, expecting that those test classes will be discovered under the package:

(In trait)

```
trait AbstractPackageTests {

  val name: String

  class Suite1 extends FunSpec {

    describe(name) {

      it("test 1") {}

      it("test 2") {}
    }
  }

  class Suite2 extends FunSpec {
    describe(name) {

      it("test 3") {}

      it("test 4") {}
    }
  }
}
```

(In package 1)

```
package com.spike.scalatest_spike

package object facet1 extends FunSpec with AbstractPackageTests {
  override val name: String = "facet 1"

  class Suite3 extends FunSpec {
    describe(name) {

      it("test 5") {}

    }
  }
}
```

(In package 2)

```
package com.spike.scalatest_spike

package object facet2 extends AbstractPackageTests {
  override val name: String = "facet 2"
}
```

Unfortunately it appears that none of these classes (Suite1, Suite2, Sutie3) can be discovered when I invoke scalatest to run all the test under `com.spike.scalatest_spike`, the classes seems to be ignored in class discovery.

What changes should I make on my project or/and scalatest sourcecode to make it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SBT to invoke the testing then ensure sources are in src/test/scala or src/test/java as documented: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html

If you're using a jar with the `java` or `scala` commands, it's possible your test classes are missing from the jar. The former method may be easier since it doesn't require a jar to have all your test classes.